# Stuck on Algebra › Solving by multiplying

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

[image]I'm practicing maths and got stuck at certain point. Isn't the answer 48? If I write 48, it says "try again". Correct me if I'm wrong.

[please see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufQsf.png)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  The question asks for the sale price *in terms of $p$*

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I might not fully understand the question as is "in terms of p –" what is the sale price...
Is it the same question: what was the original price?  
   and 
in terms of p – what is the sale price?

Comment: The original price was \$$48$, but the sale price is $\dfrac34p$

Comment: oh right, the answer is 3/4p, whitten just like that, not just number - 36. Many thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that the original price was $\$48$,

but the question is asking for the sale price in terms of the original price $p$,

so the answer is $\dfrac34p$.